# Lighting candles when eating out on erev yontif

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, candle-lighting, hachnasat-orchim-guests

[A recent question asked about lighting candles when eating out on Friday night](/q/64569):

> If one is going out to eat (such as at a simcha), should Shabbos candles be lit at home or at the hall? I heard that some rabbis do not allow candles to be lit at the hall in the shul but instruct whomever is making the simcha to advise their guests to light at their host's home where they will be sleeping.

That question [was answered](/a/64571): light at home and spend time at night with the flames; some say that if that's not possible then you can light where you eat, even with saying a blessing. (See there for more detail.)

My question asks about lighting candles erev yontif.  Is the answer the same as for erev Shabbat or are there differences in the two candle lightings?

Answer (score 1):

This actually can be answered by logic. On Yom Tov one is allowed to light a candle from an existing flame. As a result, one would light the candle at home upon returning there. Since one would do this at once, the light of the candles would now be used and be yotzei lighting the candles.

[For example](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/114392/jewish/Holiday-Candle-Lighting-Procedure.htm) Thus, if one eats out, one can light the Yom Tov candles upon returning home (from the stove flame or lit yahrtzeit candle).

> while it is forbidden to create a flame on a holiday, it is permitted
>   to light a candle using a pre-existing flame, such as another candle
>   that was kindled before the holiday, a gas range which has been left
>   on, or a pilot flame
>
> On the first night of a holiday: Ideally the candles should be lit –
>   just as on every Friday afternoon – eighteen minutes before sunset.3
>   However, the candles can be lit anytime before the holiday meal.4 If
>   the candles are lit after sunset, they should be lit from a
>   pre-existing flame. Exceptions: a) If the first night of the holiday
>   is Friday night, the candles must be kindled before sunset. b) If the
>   first night of the holiday is Saturday night, the candles must be
>   kindled after nightfall (from a pre-existing flame).
>
> On the second night of a holiday: The candles should be lit, from a
>   pre-existing flame, after nightfall.5 (Additionally, all preparations
>   for the candle lighting, such as arranging the candlesticks and
>   candles, may not start before nightfall.6) If the second night of the
>   holiday is Friday night, the candles must be kindled before sunset,
>   also from a pre-existing flame.

Comment: But what is the purpose of lighting yontif candles?  Is the purpose the same for Shabbat and yontif? On Shabbat you light to help you enjoy your meal at home.  On yontif, if you eat away from home and come home and light and go right to sleep, have you used the light to help you enjoy the yontif?

Comment: @YehudaW That is a different question.

Comment: @sabbahillel No, that's this question. He asked what should be done in this case, not what possible ways of lighting flames are there.

Comment: @DoubleAA I added a comment to show that you would use the light of the candles before going to sleep.

Comment: If one lit at the hall, must one light again at home? Why or why not?  If one must light again at home, is one of the two lightings a bracha not needed?